# PhoneGap media plugin stop the audio not working

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova

I am workign with PhoneGap 3.0.0 and my confic.xml file does have the needed plugins.  I can start saying that my sound do start when i run my code, and that everything else works.  Just 1 thing dont want to work.

I am using Jquery Mobile.

I cant stop the audio.

I am calling a function called "stopAudio()" that read a global variable "my_audio" and fire of the "stop()" function.

Here is my code.

Index.html

```
<a href="#stopaudio" data-role="button">Stop Audio</a>
```

AudioHandler.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var my_media = null;

function playAudio(url) {
    try {

        var my_media = new Media(url,
            // success callback
            function () {
                my_media.release();
            },
            // error callback
            function (err) {
                my_media.release();
            });

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}   


function stopAudio() {
    my_media.stop();
}
```

controller.js

```
$("#stopaudio").click(function() {
    stopAudio();
});
```

Example usage:

```
playAudio("/android_assets/www/mysound.mp3");
```

So i have these 3 files.  What i posted is a small amount of the content, but the other content in those files have nothing to do with the audio.  I did also try and comment everything out and so forth.

So, basicly the "controller.js" is the file where the click are detected, and from there the function "stopAudio()" are called that comes from AudioHandler.js.

My audio do start on startup of the phone.

I cant stop the audio.

Im running out of ideas, any help would be welcome :-)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `my_media` as a local variable here:

```
try {
        var my_media = new Media(url,
```

You want it to be global, so remove the `var`:

```
function playAudio(url) {
    try {

        my_media = new Media(url,
            // success callback
            function () {
                my_media.release();
            },
            // error callback
            function (err) {
                my_media.release();
            });

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, im blind, it works.  Ofc, how did i miss this.  But thats how things are sometimes.  Thanks again man.  I need to wait like 3 mins before i can close this question.